# Как вызвать handler из друго метода

Tags: c#, winforms, color

Как сделать чтобы при потере фокуса элемент listbox-а перекрашивался в другой цвет?

```
private void listBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Как перерисовать выделенный элемент?
}

this.listBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.listBox1_DrawItem);

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{

    e.DrawBackground();

    bool isItemSelected = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected);
    int itemIndex = e.Index;
    if (itemIndex >= 0 && itemIndex < listBox1.Items.Count)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        // Background Color
        SolidBrush backgroundColorBrush = new SolidBrush((isItemSelected) ? Color.Red : Color.White);
        g.FillRectangle(backgroundColorBrush, e.Bounds);

        // Set text color
        string itemText = listBox1.Items[itemIndex].ToString();

        SolidBrush itemTextColorBrush = (isItemSelected)
            ? new SolidBrush(Color.White)
            : new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        g.DrawString(itemText, e.Font, itemTextColorBrush, listBox1.GetItemRectangle(itemIndex).Location);

        // Clean up
        backgroundColorBrush.Dispose();
        itemTextColorBrush.Dispose();
    }

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю следующие улучшения кода:

1. Листбокс оформлен как отдельный контрол;
2. В методе отрисовки переиспользуются объекты `SolidBrush`. Они не создаются и не очищаются постоянно;
3. Убран весь лишний код;
4. Перерисовка контрола не происходит, если нет выбранных элементов;
5. Перерисовка задана только для выбранного элемента, а не всего контрола.

Код класса:

```
public sealed class ListBoxEx : ListBox
{
    private bool isMouseOver;

    public ListBoxEx()
    {
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        MouseEnter += (sender, args) => MouseEnterOrLeave(true);
        MouseLeave += (sender, args) => MouseEnterOrLeave(false);
    }

    private void MouseEnterOrLeave(bool isMouseEnter)
    {
        if (SelectedIndex < 0) return;
        isMouseOver = isMouseEnter;
        var rect = GetItemRectangle(SelectedIndex);
        Invalidate(rect);
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);

        e.DrawBackground();
        var grfx = e.Graphics;

        var isItemSelected = (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected;

        var backBrush = isItemSelected ? (isMouseOver ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Green) : Brushes.White;
        grfx.FillRectangle(backBrush, e.Bounds);

        var itemText = Items[e.Index].ToString();
        var textBrush = isItemSelected ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Black;
        grfx.DrawString(itemText, e.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds);

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

Для настройки цветов их нужно вынести в свойства и при изменении создавить новые  объекты `SolidBrush` в приватных полях для кеширования.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете при наведении\убирании мыши с элемента управления заставлять этот элемент управления себя перерисовывать:

```
listBox1.MouseEnter += delegate { listBox1.Invalidate(); };
listBox1.MouseLeave += delegate { listBox1.Invalidate(); };
```

А в методе отрисовки добавить соответствующую логику, которая будет по разному рисовать элемент управления в зависимости от позиции мыши, например:

```
SolidBrush backgroundColorBrush = new SolidBrush((isItemSelected) ? Color.Red : Color.White);
if (isItemSelected && listBox1.DisplayRectangle.Contains(listBox1.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
    backgroundColorBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);

g.FillRectangle(backgroundColorBrush, e.Bounds);
```